# LDAP secondary group working for only some users

Tags: openldap, ubuntu-12.04, debian-wheezy

On an Ubuntu box, I'm having issues with LDAP secondary groups for one user, sabnzbd. The user should be a part of the media group.

```
daniel@server:~$ id sabnzbd
uid=4996(sabnzbd) gid=4996(sabnzbd) groups=4996(sabnzbd)

daniel@server:~$ id transmission
uid=4998(transmission) gid=4998(transmission) groups=4998(transmission),4999(media)

daniel@server:~$ ldapsearch -D cn=admin,dc=home -W -H ldaps://ldap.home -b dc=home '(&(objectclass=posixGroup)(|(memberUid=sabnzbd)))'
Enter LDAP Password: 
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=home> with scope subtree
# filter: (&(objectclass=posixGroup)(|(memberUid=sabnzbd)))
# requesting: ALL
#

# media, Groups, home
dn: cn=media,ou=Groups,dc=home
objectClass: posixGroup
objectClass: top
cn: media
gidNumber: 4999
memberUid: elle
memberUid: daniel
memberUid: sabnzbd
memberUid: transmission
memberUid: sickbeard

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1

daniel@server:~$ getent group media
media:*:4999:elle,daniel,sabnzbd,transmission,sickbeard

(excerpt from nsswitch.conf)
passwd: files ldap
group: files ldap
shadow: files ldap
```

On a Debian box, it works fine. The difference is the Ubuntu box is using libpam-ldapd (same behavior with libpam-ldap) and the Debian box is using libnss-ldapd. I found that netatalk wasn't authenticating LDAP users with libnss-ldapd, so I switched to libpam-ldap, then libpam-ldapd. netatalk now works as expected, but I'm having this problem with the secondary user.

Comment: PAM and NSS do different things (you need both installed and setup). What's the output of `getent group media`? Can you paste the contents of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`?

Comment: Yes, they are different, but I was pointing out that the mechanism of LDAP authentication is different.